# Using WinUI3 with only C++

Tags: c++, winui-3

I am looking at creating a rich interactive application with modern look and feel. My business logic is completely in C++ and intending to use C++ for the GUI aspect too. Have been currently trying out Win32 so far. Now, am intending to move to WinUI 3.
Can I use WinUI 3 to work purely on C++ and achieve all modern experiences, touch gesturess, data grids etc. I also do not want to use XAML but create the UI programmatically. I could not find a lot of references using C++. Most of the material is using C#.

Does anyone has any inputs/suggestions or some good reference materials for my use-case ?

Comment: C# is easier, that's why you will find more sample than C++, but as WinUI3 is WinRT (language agnostic), you "only" need bindings/projection to use it. C++ is a first class choice (coupled with C++/WinRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt which makes it much easier). As for not using XAML, this is clearly another story. Coding WinUI3 w/o XAML is clearly not a good idea, and probably impossible.

Comment: How did you decide?  I'm in the same boat. Still waiting until 1.5 comes out April 2024 before making the next decision. I have wrappers already to move the GUI layer into Android but still want to use C++ on all three desktops systems

Comment: I have a guide here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5376701/The-guide-to-WinUI3-for-a-Cplusplus-Win32-programm

Answer (score 0):

I have used XAML only for a general layout of static items like App, MainWindow and pages (for navigation) but most of my code is written in C++(17 and later) I have found you can populate things like Grids and TreeViews with this type of items like below:

```
Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::TreeViewNode rootNode;
rootNode.Content(winrt::box_value(ItemName().Text()));
ItemData().RootNodes().Append(rootNode);
for (auto const& ItemDetail : Items(winrt::to_string(ItemName().Text())))
{
    Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::TreeViewNode detailNode;
    detailNode.Content(winrt::box_value(winrt::to_hstring(ItemDetail)));
    rootNode.Children().Append(detailNode);
}
```

The ItemData() is a TreeView